# Solo evitar salto de línea en un txt

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando abrir un txt con fopen(), pero no reconoce los saltos de línea; por lo que quise eliminarlos usando:

```
$file = trim($file); <br>
$file = str_replace("", "", $file);<br>
$file = str_replace("\r", "", $file); <br>
```

Pero no lo toma y sí o sí termino agarrando el txt y eliminando los enter a mano.

¿Hay alguna forma? Probé varias y ninguna me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza las distintas formas utilizadas para escribir los saltos de línea:

```
$file = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\r\n"), "", $file);
```

Comment: Me devuelve esto

expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
$cons_usuario="root";
$cons_contra="";
$cons_base_datos="denis"; //nombrde de cada uno
$cons_equipo="localhost";

$obj_conexion=mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);

if (!$obj_conexion){
    echo "<h3>No se ha podido conectar PHP - MySQL, verifique sus datos.</h3><hr><br>";
} else {
    echo "<h3>Conexion Exitosa PHP - MySQL</h3><hr><br>";
}

$file = fopen("winestore.data", "r") or exit("No se puede abrir el archivo.");
$file = str_replace("", "", $file);
$file = str_replace(array("\r","\r\n","\n"), "", $file);

set_time_limit(9000);

while(!feof($file)){
      $insert = fgets($file);
      if (mysqli_query($obj_conexion, $insert)) {
        echo "Fila insertada exitosamente";
    } else {
        echo "Error al insertar fila: " . mysqli_error($obj_conexion);
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

?>

Comment: puedes añadir el contenido del archivo "winestore.data"? a ver si podemos ver que formato tiene y quizas hay una manera mas facil de borrar esos espacios...

Comment: El archivo tiene 10k renglones (es un ingreso de tabla sql). Te puedo pasar un pedazo. Igual es un enter en un create table y otro create table. La extension es un .data

Comment: pon lo que creas necesario, no hace falta poner un griton de lineas :)  el asunto es que publiques una parte que se pueda analizar, quizas hay otro modo (o utilizas un formato que ya tiene php y se puede leer directamente...)